# How to disable auto resizing of windows when moved to the top?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

When I move a window close to the top, it snaps to maximum size. I am using Ubuntu 18.04, GNOME 3.28.2.

### How do I disable that? I searched about six months ago, no way to disable back then.

1/5/19
Yes, solved!  Thank you!

- These two worked on my Ubuntu 18.04

  1. `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling false`
  2. dconf-editor
- These did not work

  1. GNOME Tweaks  (disable "Edge Tiling" not available)
  2. `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false`

Thank you Kulfy, Hamza Saeed, vanadium, PRATAP.

Answer (score 8):

**Command Line way:**

by default the value for edge-tiling is set to true..

check the value with the below command
`gsettings get org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling`

then set the value to false by below command
`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling false`

Example:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling
true
$ gsettings set org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling false
$
```

**GUI way**

Open dconf-editor, if not installed install it by below command
`sudo apt update && sudo apt install dconf-editor`

search for "mutter" --> edge-tiling --> turn off the button.

[image]

Comment: I don't think setting org.gnome.mutter edge-tiling will do this. I tried your method. Results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oINY.gif

Comment: Indeed, only works with the org.gnome.shell.overrides key.

Answer (score 3):

To disable auto-resizing of the windows, open a terminal and run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false
```

Answer (score 2):

Install GNOME Tweaks from the Software Centre

Go to the **Windows** tab and disable **Edge Tiling**

Updated:

[image: 2nd option]

Comment: Hamza there is no Edge tiling option under Windows in Tweaks at least in my main installation. Can you please share a screenshot? Thanks :)

Comment: @Kulfy updated!

Comment: You most probably have a newer release of Ubuntu, but the question was originally asked for Ubuntu 18.04 which does not have this specific option as @Kulfy mentioned.