# Ubuntu 21.04 - how do I turn off hot top edge maximising windows

Tags: gnome-shell, window, settings, 21.04

How do I turn off the top edge of the display from maximising windows in Ubuntu 21.04?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable auto resizing of windows when moved to the top?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107089/how-to-disable-auto-resizing-of-windows-when-moved-to-the-top) (this question was itself flagged as a duplicate, but I find its answers much better than the other one)

Answer (score 1):

I installed gnome-tweaks and turned off edge-tiling. It worked for me.